# How to assign new numerical keys to an array and sort based on the original keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with numerical indices, which looks like this (after I unset some elements):

```
$array = [
    23 => 'banana',
    3 => 'apple',
    5 => 'pear',
];
```

Which function do I use to reorder them based on their key order to:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'apple',
    1 => 'pear',
    2 => 'banana',
];
```

I tried some of the sort functions but none of them provided the output I need.

Comment: Comparison of all the common sorting functions: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: And the dupe target closed as a dupe points to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224821/how-to-reindex-an-array ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to sort the array by key value use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php):

```
ksort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => apple
    [5] => pear
    [23] => banana
)
```

That will preserve the keys however. To reassign keys for an array from 0 onwards use [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the result:

```
ksort($array);
$array_with_new_keys = array_values($array); // sorted by original key order
print_r($array_with_new_keys);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => pear
    [2] => banana
)
```

Comment: Cletus, he doesn't want to sort by value (look: apple, pear, banana). sort() will do: apple, BANANA, pear. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 11):

[ksort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) will sort by key, then get the values with [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and that will create a new array with keys from `0` to `n-1`.

```
ksort($array)
$array = array_values( $array );
```

Of course, you don't need ksort if it's already sorted by key. You might as well use array_values() directly.

Answer (score 4):

```
$arrayOne = array('one','two','three'); //You set an array with certain elements
unset($array[1]);                       //You unset one or more elements.
$arrayTwo = array_values($arrayOnw);    //You reindex the array into a new one.

print_r($arrayTwo);                     //Print for prove.
```

The `print_r` results are:

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => three )
```