# How to retain the index 0 when using unset in removing index

Tags: php, laravel

I have a session variable like this:

$list = Session::get('list_id')

the $list variable value has a value of `Array ( [0] => A,  [1] => B,[2] => C, [4] => D)`

when I am using  `unset($list [0]);`

I am getting a value of `Array ([1] => B,[2] => C, [4] => D)`

The problem that I am getting is all of my parameters has a parameters of `$list[0]` I need the index 0 always, so that value that I am looking for after I remove the index 0 is `Array ([0] => B,[1] => C, [2] => D)`

so that I can store it again on my session.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: use `array_values` to reindex the array, then you can use index zero again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reindex an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224821/how-to-reindex-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_values` function if you are sure your array has only numerical index keys.

See this link for more details; https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: it has already been answered many times. Please flag it as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224821/how-to-reindex-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Do not use unset.
array_shift — Shift an element off the beginning of array

```
$removedElement = array_shift($yourArray);
```

array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down.